# Is there any way to Show Google Admob in Android Recycler View

Tags: android, listview, admob, android-recyclerview

I want to show Ads using google Admob in my app's Main Activity. I have placed all code requires for showing ads by getting help from google-developers site but when I run my app, ads are not displaying. I don't know what is the problem occurring:

`MainActivity`:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private View view;
    private Button button;


    String[] mDataSet = new String[]{
           "1","2"
    };

    String[] data = new String[]{"Sample Activty "

    };
    private Context context;
    private Intent sharingIntent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

     mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
                new RecyclerItemClickListener(context, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                        // do whatever
                        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "position = " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
                        context.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                })
        );

 // use a linear layout manager
        LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SimpleDividerItemDecoration(getResources()));

        // specify an adapter (see also next example)
        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(mDataSet);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

And this is `MyAdapter.java`:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
   // private String[] mDataset;
    public String[] mDataset;
    private String mItem;
    private Context context;

    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemClickListener;

    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
   // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
   // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
   public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {
       // each data item is just a string in this case
       public TextView mTextView;
       public TextView mFootView;

       public ViewHolder(View v) {
           super(v);
          // context = v.getContext();
           mTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.firstLine);
          // mFootView= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.secondLine);
       }
   }
   // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
   public MyAdapter(String[] myDataset) {
       mDataset = myDataset;
   }

   // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
   @Override
   public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,int viewType) {
       // create a new view
       View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
               .inflate(R.layout.item_main, parent, false);
       // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
       ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
       return vh;
}
   // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
       // - get element from your dataset at this position
       // - replace the contents of the view with that element
       holder.mTextView.setText(mDataset[position]);
   }

   // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
   @Override
   public int getItemCount() {
       return mDataset.length;
      // return mDataset.size();
   }
}
```

And this `activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/main_redrose"
    >

    <!-- A RecyclerView with some commonly used attributes -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:divider="@drawable/list_divider"/>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27969384/embedding-ads-within-recyclerview

Comment: @penguin this is not working beczuse that method only works with listview

Comment: have you checked my answer, is it what you asked

Comment: Hi Tauseef. Was the answer below helpful to you, so that you might accept it via the tick mark?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Embedding ads within Recyclerview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27969384/embedding-ads-within-recyclerview)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Here is complete example. I just created an example app for you.

**Main Activity**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String TAG = Main.class.getSimpleName();
    private Context mContext;
    private List<MyListModel> mList;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mContext = this;
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mList = new ArrayList<MyListModel>();

        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            MyListModel myString = new MyListModel();
            myString.setName(i+" - I love Paris");
            myString.setViewType(1);
            mList.add(myString);
        }

        //Place two Admob Ads at position index 1 and 5 in recyclerview
        MyListModel myString1 = new MyListModel();
        myString1.setViewType(2);
        mList.add(1,myString1);

        MyListModel myString2 = new MyListModel();
        myString2.setViewType(2);
        mList.add(5,myString2);



        // use a linear layout manager
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        // specify an adapter (see also next example)
        mAdapter = new ListAdopter(this, mList);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
}
```

**RecyclerViewAdopter**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import java.util.List;

public class RecyclerViewAdopter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{

    private Context mContext;
    private List<MyListModel> mList;

    public RecyclerViewAdopter(Context mContext, List<MyListModel> mList) {
        this.mList = mList;
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView name;
        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView_name);
        }
    }

    public static class ViewHolderAdMob extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public AdView mAdView;
        public ViewHolderAdMob(View view) {
            super(view);
            mAdView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.adView);
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                    .build();
            mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        switch(viewType){
            case 1:{
                View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_1, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new MyViewHolder(v);
                break;
            }
            case 2:{
                View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_admob, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolderAdMob(v);
                break;
            }
        }
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        MyListModel model = mList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());

        switch(holder.getItemViewType()){
            case 1:{
                MyViewHolder viewHolder = (MyViewHolder) holder;
                viewHolder.name.setText(model.getName());
                break;
            }
            case 2:{
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return mList.get(position).getViewType();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mList.size();
    }
}
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.kyanogen.ui.ScyllaListFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@color/primary_dark"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
        android:scrollbarSize="4dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**list_item_1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listView_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="30dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**list_item_admob.xml**

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

[image]

***Update 9-12-2016***

**MyListModel**

```
public class MyListModel {

    private String name;
    private int viewType;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getViewType() {
        return viewType;
    }

    public void setViewType(int viewType) {
        this.viewType = viewType;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Sophie unfortunately I do not have code now, I created a sample project when I posted this answer.

Comment: Inside ad ? May be, not sure about that. If you want to show your own views instead of admob then, answer is Yes.

Comment: what about if your using gson to parse json

Comment: Recycler view scrolling is getting stuck when adding multiple ads in recycler view with particular interval. Is there any way to improve the performance.?