# Problems loading AdView inside a RecyclerView

Tags: android-recyclerview, adview

I've been looking in Stackoverflow how to integrate an `AdView` inside a `RecyclerView`. I've been following these posts:

[One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27969384/embedding-ads-within-recyclerview), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33706186/is-there-any-way-to-show-google-admob-in-android-recycler-view)

Basically the way to do it is calling `loadAd` inside `onCreateViewHolder` or inside the constructor of the `ViewHolder`.

Either way, this is my implementation:

**JAVA**

```
public class AdExpressViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public AdExpressViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        final AdView adView = (AdView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .build();
        adView.loadAd(request);
    }
}
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            ads:adUnitId="**********************"
            ads:adSize="BANNER">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**The problem is:** when I scroll the RecyclerView, it seems to load on the UI thread since it gets stuck, only the first time. The rest of the times is ok.

This is the video that demonstrates it:

[Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-V0KHNRjbE_c01uemlBbjV6XzA/view?usp=sharing)

As you can see, the first one is blocking the UI, but not the second one.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

---

EDIT

I've tried to load a conventional `AdView` in an activity, fixed. It works and it doesn't seem to be load in the UI Thread. Seems it's just happening in the `RecyclerView`.

---

After 3 weeks, I've done a Method profiling, and this is what I've got out:

[image]

You can realise the red spots. Those are 2 different `AdView` loading, while the rest are 38 normal custom views of mine.

To be more concrete, these are the functions, so it's regarding 100% the `AdView`:

[image]

Comment: hi is this bug fixed now how are loading ads in recycler view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems a bug of the Ads SDK for Android and it's not been fixed, at least until v9.4.0.

More information here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-admob-ads-sdk/ui$20thread%7Csort:relevance/google-admob-ads-sdk/k4IFZA_QGT4/3gMHaCPPBQAJ