# All data not shown but AdMobs with RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, admob, retrofit

I'm trying to show a list of data with RecyclerView and add an AdMob after 3 data showed. I have followed [this stackoverflow Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33706186/is-there-any-way-to-show-google-admob-in-android-recycler-view) because it's almost the same as my code but I'm using Retrofit.

But my result is just showing test AdMob rows only... It's not show my data's `name` String.

This is my MainActivity:

```
public class Nilai extends AppCompatActivity implements NilaiView {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefresh;

    NilaiPresenter presenter;
    RecyclerViewAdopter adapter;
    List<modelNilai> score;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nilai);

        MobileAds.initialize(this, "ID_APP");

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        swipeRefresh = findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        presenter = new NilaiPresenter(this);
        presenter.getNilai();

        swipeRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(
                () -> presenter.getNilai()
        );

    }

    @Override
    public void showLoading() {
        swipeRefresh.setRefreshing(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void hideLoading() {
        swipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onGetNilai(List<modelNilai> scores) {
        adapter = new RecyclerViewAdopter(Nilai.this, scores);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        score = scores;

        for (int i = 0; i <= scores.size(); i += 3)
        {
            modelNilai myString2 = new modelNilai();
            myString.setId(i);
            scores.add(i,myString);
        }

    }

}
```

My Adapter:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdopter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{

    private Context mContext;
    private List<modelNilai> mList;

    public RecyclerViewAdopter(Context mContext, List<modelNilai> mList) {
        this.mList = mList;
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView name;
        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            name = view.findViewById(R.id.namaSoal);
        }
    }

    public static class ViewHolderAdMob extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public AdView mAdView;
        public ViewHolderAdMob(View view) {
            super(view);
            mAdView = view.findViewById(R.id.adView);

            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                    .addTestDevice("CEE26DC1A5BBF0E603B08A5460483046")
                    .build();
            mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        switch(viewType){
            case 1:
            {
                View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_nilai_ad, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new MyViewHolder(v);
                break;
            }
            case 2:
            default:
            {
                View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.banner_ad_row, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolderAdMob(v);
                break;
            }
        }
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        modelNilai model = mList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());

        switch(holder.getItemViewType()){
            case 1:{
                MyViewHolder viewHolder = (MyViewHolder) holder;
                viewHolder.name.setText(model.getName());
                break;
            }
            case 2:{
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position)
    {
        return mList.get(position).getId();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mList.size();
    }
}
```

My presenter:

```
public class NilaiPresenter {
    private NilaiView view;

    public NilaiPresenter(NilaiView view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    void getNilai() {
        view.showLoading();

        ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<List<modelNilai>> call = apiInterface.getNilai();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<modelNilai>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<List<modelNilai>> call, @NonNull Response<List<modelNilai>> response) {
                view.hideLoading();
                if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null) {
                    view.onGetNilai(response.body());
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<List<modelNilai>> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                view.hideLoading();
                view.onRequestError(t.getLocalizedMessage());

            }
        });
    }
}
```

My model class:

```
public class modelNilai {
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("id") private int id_nilai;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("name") private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }    
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

And My view interface:

```
public interface NilaiView {
    void showLoading();
    void hideLoading();
    void onGetNilai(List<modelNilai> scores);
}
```

Result on phone:

[image: screenshot]

It should show something like 3 rows of name and 1 row of Admob, and repeat that again per 4 rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parhaps, the `getItemViewType()` method should be like this:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position)
{
    return (position + 1) % 4 == 0 ? 2 : 1;
}
```

---

You also have to modify the `getItemCount()` method. Because it should return the count of all of your `mList` rows and **PLUS** of your Admob rows.

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mList.size() + mList.size / 4;
}
```

In addition to that the `onBindViewHolder` method is affected:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    modelNilai model = mList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition() - holder.getAdapterPosition() / 4);

    if ((position + 1) % 4 != 0) {
        MyViewHolder viewHolder = (MyViewHolder) holder;
        viewHolder.name.setText(model.getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: its working,, but should i use `for (int i = 0; i <= scores.size(); i +=3)` on activity.. its look annoying for me.

Comment: i check total row on my database is 5 rows. but i got only 4 rows. can u make it auto ? not manual.

Comment: @RendiChs I didn't notice that (about MainActivity). Ok, wait...

Comment: @RendiChs Ok. If your current problem has been cleared, please accept my answer to finish this Q&A. If there is another problem related your program, you can post a new question.

Comment: Sorry,, but ur answer still not perfect sir.. example i got 5 rows.. it show all, but rows on 4, its REPLACE to AdMob. can u fix it ?

Comment: @RendiChs I think that is another problem even if it is of the same program. It may be caused from your removal of the `for (int i = 0; i <= scores.size(); i +=3)` in MainActivity. Please separate that issue as a new question.

Comment: let me clear it sir.. i have remove that looping in MainActivity..
now im asking ur looping `return (position + 1) % 4 == 0 ? 2 : 1;` << it is replace my item row, result look like 1, 2, 3, ad, 5.. my row 4 has been replace to ad, can fix it on result, 1, 2, 3, ad, 4, 5.

Comment: @RendiChs That means your code had two problems from the start. Ok, wait...

Comment: ok thanks sir i have accept ur answer.. but its look annoying for `mlist.size` there is only `mList.size()` and i got error `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 5, Size: 5`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213467/discussion-between-hata-and-rendi-chs).