# How to make ads in RecyclerView display different contents

Tags: android, admob, android-recyclerview

I am applying [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27969384/embedding-ads-within-recyclerview) to display admob ads after every 7th item in RecyclerViews on phones and after every 13th item on tablets. The problem I am having is that all the ads are displaying the same content (message, title, picture). I think it's because they're all the same as unit.

Now, the items in RecyclerView ranges from a minimum of 10 to about 2500 (if the user can scroll to that extend).

I was thinking about creating several ads units and assigning each ad unit to a specific position. But this is not very feasible as it'll result to more than 350 ads units and it's against big G's policy.

So, I don't know if you have a better solution.

Comment: If ads are too many, can't you make some logic to show them 
more rarely? For example show ad on item position 7, 21 (7 + 7*2), 49 (7 + 21*2) ecc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution might be very simple: less ads.

Even if you have 2500 items in your `RecyclerView`, I highly doubt anyone will take the time to scroll through all of them. Most people will just view the first couple of items, although this might depend on the kind of content you're showing.

So I would suggest to only show ads in the first 50 (or something) items. And then lower the rate of the ads to like 1 in 100 or something. Or you could take a look at how Facebook is showing ads. And don't forget that people don't like ads!

But if you really want to show that much ads, you can also re-use some of them. It's not weird to show the same ads several times in a `RecyclerView` with 2500 items.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does that mean I'll create 50+ adunits?

Comment: Thats all up to you :) You can use any amount you want, depends on how often you want the same ad to show