# Android Admob Native ads using recycle view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, admob, native-ads

How can i integrate admob native ads in recycle view?
i'm tried but not able to integrate properly.

Comment: Why integrate in recycler? Just make it stick in a layout.

Comment: Refer to the following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27969384/embedding-ads-within-recyclerview

Comment: Refer to the following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27969384/embedding-ads-within-recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

You can inflate AdMob view by using a different item type parameter on your adapter. You can find how to implement different item type on a recycler view on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25914003/recyclerview-and-handling-different-type-of-row-inflation)

You can also decide the position of the ad.