# how to place ads in between recyclerview

Tags: android, listview, admob, android-recyclerview

i need to place ads in between recyclerview, i tried one method it works nice and ads loads but problem is ads are overlapped on list view. anyone please help me thank you in advance

Below is the code for Adapter.class

```
    public class NewsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {

    private static final int CONTENT_TYPE = 0;
    private static final int AD_TYPE = 1;
    private int[] viewTypes;
    int Holderid;
    private List<Newslist> newslists;
    private Context context;


    public NewsAdapter(List<Newslist> newslists, Context context) {
        super();
        //Getting all the news updates
        this.newslists = newslists;
        this.context=context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        //Inflate the layout, initialize the View Holder
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (viewType == CONTENT_TYPE) {
            View newsView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.news_list, parent, false);
            holder=new ItemViewHolder(newsView);
        } else {
            View adView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.native_ads, parent, false);
            holder=new AdViewHolder(adView);
        }
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        if (position % 6 == 3) {
            AdViewHolder holder = (AdViewHolder) viewHolder;
            //Load the Ad
            AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
                    .build();
            holder.adView.loadAd(request);

        } else  {

            ItemViewHolder holder = (ItemViewHolder) viewHolder;
            Newslist newslist = newslists.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());

            holder.message.setText(newslist.getMessage());

            //Image loading using singleton class
            ImageLoader imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
            holder.imageView.setImageUrl(newslist.getImageurl(), imageLoader);
            holder.imageView.setDrawingCacheBackgroundColor(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
            holder.time.setText(newslist.getTime());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return newslists.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (position % 6 ==3)
            return AD_TYPE;
        return CONTENT_TYPE;
    }
    // return newslists.get(position).getViewType();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
    }
}

class ItemViewHolder extends ViewHolder {

    TextView message;
    NetworkImageView imageView;
    TextView time;
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

    ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        message = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.headline);
        time = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.time);
        imageView = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.networkImageView2);
        relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
    }
}

class AdViewHolder extends ViewHolder {
    NativeExpressAdView adView;

    AdViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        adView = (NativeExpressAdView) v.findViewById(R.id.nativeAdView);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27969384/embedding-ads-within-recyclerview

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Embedding ads within Recyclerview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27969384/embedding-ads-within-recyclerview)

Comment: Can you show what your R.id.nativeAdView is in the xml layout?

Answer (score 6):

```
    public class NewsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {
    
        private static final int CONTENT_TYPE = 0;
        private static final int AD_TYPE = 1;
        private int[] viewTypes;
        int Holderid;
        private List<Newslist> newslists;
        private Context context;
    
    
        public NewsAdapter(List<Newslist> newslists, Context context) {
            super();
            //Getting all the news updates
            this.newslists = newslists;
            this.context=context;
        }
    
        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            //Inflate the layout, initialize the View Holder
            ViewHolder holder = null;
            if (viewType == CONTENT_TYPE) {
                View newsView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.news_list, parent, false);
                holder=new ItemViewHolder(newsView);
            } else if(viewType == AD_TYPE){
                View adView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.native_ads, parent, false);
                holder=new AdViewHolder(adView);
            }
            return holder;
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final NewsAdapter.ItemViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    
         if(holder.HOLDER != 1){
               final int pos=position-(position / 6);
    
                 final Newslist objnewslist=newslists.get(pos);
    
                holder.message.setText(objnewslist.getMessage());
    
                //Image loading using singleton class
                ImageLoader imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
                holder.imageView.setImageUrl(objnewslist.getImageurl(), imageLoader);
                holder.imageView.setDrawingCacheBackgroundColor(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                holder.time.setText(objnewslist.getTime());
            }
        }
    
        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
    if(newslists.size() > 0) {
        return newslists.size() + (newslists.size()/6);
    }
            return newslists.size();
        }
    
        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
           if ((position+1)%6==0){
                return AD_TYPE;
            }
            return CONTENT_TYPE;
        }
        // return newslists.get(position).getViewType();
    }
    
    
    class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    
        TextView message;
        NetworkImageView imageView;
        TextView time;
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
        int HOLDER;
        AdView madview;
    
        ItemViewHolder(View itemView , int viewType) {
            super(itemView);
            if (viewType == AD_TYPE) {
                    madview = (AdView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.adView);
                    AdRequest adreq = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
                    madview.loadAd(adreq);
                    HOLDER = AD_TYPE;
                }else {
            message = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.headline);
            time = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.time);
            imageView = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.networkImageView2);
            relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
HOLDER = CONTENT_TYPE;
            }
        }
    }
```

Check the above code this works fine.

Comment: If you find the answer relevant kindly tick the answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `ItemViewHolder`, you should put `viewType` value, and getItemCount() should return newslists.size() + Math.round(newslists.size()/**(6 - 1)**);