# how to place ads in between recyclerview items

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, admob

I need to place ads in between recyclerview in my videoplayer app, I gone thorough some stack overflow questions here and some examples in GitHub here but I am not such successful.
i have two layout grid and list view for videos, i want to add two formats of native ads for both list and grid.

Below is the code for BaseVideoAdapter.class

'

```
 

public class BaseVideoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> implements Filterable {


    public static ArrayList<BaseModel> arrayVideoList = new ArrayList<>();
    public static ArrayList<BaseModel> arrayFilterList = new ArrayList<>();
    Activity activity;
    BottomOptionInterface anInterface;


    public BaseVideoAdapter(Activity activity, BottomOptionInterface anInterface) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.anInterface = anInterface;
        arrayFilterList = arrayVideoList;
        arrayVideoList.clear();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView;
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = null;


        if (Util.VIEW_TYPE.equals("GRID")) {
            itemView = LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.home_all_video_grid, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new MyClassView(itemView);
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = itemView.getLayoutParams();
            if (params != null) {
                WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
                int width = wm.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
                params.height = width / 2;
            }
        } else {
            itemView = LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.home_all_video_list, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new MyClassViewList(itemView);
        }

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holders, int position) {
        RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions();
        BaseModel file = arrayFilterList.get(position);
        File file1 = new File(file.getPath());
        if (file1.exists()) {
            if (Util.VIEW_TYPE.equals("GRID")) {
                MyClassView holder = (MyClassView) holders;
                holder.mThumbnail.setClipToOutline(true);
                holder.mThumbnail.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                Glide.with(activity)
                        .load(file.getPath())
                        .apply(options.centerCrop()
                                .skipMemoryCache(true)
                                .priority(Priority.LOW)
                                .format(DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888))
                        .into(holder.mThumbnail);
                if (Util.NameField) {
                    holder.mVideoTitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    String fileNameWithOutExt = FilenameUtils.removeExtension(file1.getName());
                    holder.mVideoTitle.setText(fileNameWithOutExt);
                } else {
                    holder.mVideoTitle.setText("Video");
                }

                holder.mThumbnail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        PlayerActivity playerActivity = new PlayerActivity();
                        playerActivity.SetList(arrayFilterList, position);
                        Intent in = new Intent(activity, PlayerActivity.class);
                        in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        activity.startActivity(in);
                    }
                });

                holder.mMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        anInterface.onMoreClick(file, position);
                    }
                });

            } else {
                MyClassViewList holder = (MyClassViewList) holders;
                holder.mThumbnail.setClipToOutline(true);
                holder.mThumbnail.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                Glide.with(activity)
                        .load(file.getPath())
                        .apply(options.centerCrop()
                                .skipMemoryCache(true)
                                .priority(Priority.LOW)
                                .format(DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888))
                        .into(holder.mThumbnail);

                if (Util.NameField) {
                    holder.mVideoTitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    String fileNameWithOutExt = FilenameUtils.removeExtension(file1.getName());
                    holder.mVideoTitle.setText(fileNameWithOutExt);
                } else {
                    holder.mVideoTitle.setText("Video");
                }

                if (Util.ExtensionField) {
                    holder.mVideoExt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.mVideoExt.setText("Type : " + FilenameUtils.getExtension(file1.getName()));
                } else {
                    holder.mVideoExt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                if (Util.PathField) {
                    holder.mVideoPath.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.mVideoPath.setText(file1.getParentFile().getPath());
                } else {
                    holder.mVideoPath.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                if (Util.DateField) {
                    holder.dateCV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    String dateString = new SimpleDateFormat("dd LLL yyyy").format(new Date(file1.lastModified()));
                    holder.mVideoDate.setText(dateString);
                } else {
                    holder.dateCV.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                if (Util.LengthField) {
                    holder.mVideoDuration.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    try {
                        holder.mVideoDuration.setText(Util.generateTime(file1));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        holder.mVideoDuration.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                } else {
                    holder.mVideoDuration.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                if (Util.SizeField) {
                    holder.mVideoSize.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.mVideoSize.setText(Util.getSize(file1.length()));
                } else {
                    holder.mVideoSize.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                holder.cardList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Log.e("File:", arrayFilterList.get(position).getPath());
                        PlayerActivity playerActivity = new PlayerActivity();
                        playerActivity.SetList(arrayFilterList, position);
                        Intent in = new Intent(activity, PlayerActivity.class);
                        in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        activity.startActivity(in);
                    }
                });

                holder.mMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        anInterface.onMoreClick(file, position);
                    }
                });
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayFilterList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public void add(int i, BaseModel model) {
        arrayVideoList.add(i, model);
//        arrayFilterList.add(i,model);
        notifyItemChanged(i);
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
                String charString = charSequence.toString();
                if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                    arrayFilterList = arrayVideoList;
                } else {
                    ArrayList<BaseModel> filteredList1 = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (BaseModel row : arrayVideoList) {
                        if (row.getName().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase())) {
                            filteredList1.add(row);
                        }
                    }

                    arrayFilterList = filteredList1;
                }

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = arrayFilterList;
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                arrayFilterList = (ArrayList<BaseModel>) filterResults.values;

                // refresh the list with filtered data
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }


//    public void Addall(ArrayList<BaseModel> list) {
//
//        arrayVideoList = new ArrayList<>();
//        arrayFilterList = new ArrayList<>();
//        arrayVideoList.addAll(list);
//        arrayFilterList.addAll(list);
//
//        notifyDataSetChanged();
//    }

    public class MyClassView extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ShapeableImageView mThumbnail;
        TextView mVideoTitle;
        ImageView mPlay, mMore;

        public MyClassView(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mThumbnail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mThumbnail);
            mPlay = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mPlayBtn);
            mVideoTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mVideoTitle);
            mMore = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mMore);
        }
    }

    public class MyClassViewList extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ShapeableImageView mThumbnail;
        TextView mVideoTitle, mVideoDate, mVideoDuration, mVideoPath, mVideoSize, mVideoExt;
        ImageView mMore;
        CardView cardList, dateCV;

        public MyClassViewList(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mThumbnail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mThumbnail);
            mVideoTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mVideoTitle);
            mVideoDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mVideoDate);
            dateCV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dateCV);
            mMore = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mMore);
            cardList = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardList);
            mVideoDuration = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mVideoDuration);
            mVideoPath = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mVideoPath);
            mVideoSize = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mVideoSize);
            mVideoExt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mVideoExt);



        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Embedding ads within Recyclerview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27969384/embedding-ads-within-recyclerview)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).