# Admob Native Ads after every 5 item display in recycler view android?

Tags: android-studio, android-recyclerview, admob, android-sqlite, android-adapter

I am facing the issue with my Recycler view while placing Admob ads after every 5 items. First ads display after 5 items but when swept up/down the ads display random positions. What should I change to display ads after every 5 items?

**AdapterFile:**

public class TQuoteAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TQuoteAdapter.ImageHolder> {

```
private int ad_count = 0;
List<QuotesModel> quotesList;
Context context;
int width;
DBHelper_dbfile dbHelper;
int[] grid_colors;
int c = 0;


public TQuoteAdapter(List<QuotesModel> quotesList, Context context) {
    this.quotesList = quotesList;
    this.context = context;

    dbHelper = new DBHelper_dbfile(context);
    try {
        dbHelper.openDatabase();

    } catch (SQLException sqle) {

        throw sqle;
    }

    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources()
            .getDisplayMetrics();
    width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

    grid_colors = context.getResources().getIntArray(R.array.grid_colors);
}



public static class ImageHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private NativeAdView nativeAdView;
    ImageView favIV;
    TextView quoteTV;
    LinearLayout share, copy, wapp,fbapp,instaapp;
    CardView cardView;

    public ImageHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        nativeAdView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_view);
        quoteTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.quoteTV);
        favIV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.favIV);
        share = itemView.findViewById(R.id.share);
        copy = itemView.findViewById(R.id.copy);
        wapp = itemView.findViewById(R.id.wapp);
        fbapp = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fbapp);
        instaapp = itemView.findViewById(R.id.instaapp);
        cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);

    }
}



@NonNull
@Override
public ImageHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_tquote, parent, false);

    return new ImageHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ImageHolder holder, int position) {



    if(ad_count == 5){
        AdLoader adLoader = new AdLoader.Builder(context,context.getString(R.string.native_unit_id))
                .forNativeAd(new NativeAd.OnNativeAdLoadedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onNativeAdLoaded(@NonNull NativeAd nativeAd) {

                        populateNativeAdView(nativeAd,holder.nativeAdView);

                        if (onDestroy()) {
                            nativeAd.destroy();
                        }
                    }
                })

                .withAdListener(new AdListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(LoadAdError adError) {
                        // Handle the failure by logging, altering the UI, and so on.
                    }
                })
                .withNativeAdOptions(new NativeAdOptions.Builder()
                        // Methods in the NativeAdOptions.Builder class can be
                        // used here to specify individual options settings.
                        .build())
                .build();

        adLoader.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        ad_count = 0;
    }else {
        holder.quoteTV.setText(quotesList.get(position).getQuotes());

        ad_count ++;
    }



    setAnimation(holder.itemView);

    if (quotesList.get(position).getFavourite().equals("no")) {
        holder.favIV.setImageResource(R.drawable.unpress_download);
    } else {
        holder.favIV.setImageResource(R.drawable.press_download);
    }

    holder.favIV.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if (Utills.hasPermissions(context, Utills.permissions)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, Utills.permissions, Utills.perRequest);
        } else {
            if (quotesList.get(position).getFavourite().equals("no")) {
                dbHelper.addToFavourite("yes", quotesList.get(position).getId());
                quotesList.get(position).setFavourite("yes");
            } else {
                dbHelper.addToFavourite("no", quotesList.get(position).getId());
                quotesList.get(position).setFavourite("no");
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });


    int color = grid_colors[c];
    c++;
    if (c == grid_colors.length) {
        c = 0;
    }
    holder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(color);

}

private void setAnimation(View view){
    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
    view.setAnimation(animation);

}

protected boolean onDestroy() {
    AdManager.destroyFbAd();
    return false;
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return quotesList.size();
}
private void populateNativeAdView(NativeAd nativeAd, NativeAdView nativeAdView) {
    nativeAdView.setMediaView((MediaView) nativeAdView.findViewById(R.id.media_view));
    nativeAdView.setCallToActionView(nativeAdView.findViewById(R.id.cta));
    nativeAdView.setHeadlineView(nativeAdView.findViewById(R.id.primary));
    nativeAdView.setAdvertiserView(nativeAdView.findViewById(R.id.secondary));
    nativeAdView.setStarRatingView(nativeAdView.findViewById(R.id.rating_bar));
    nativeAdView.setBodyView(nativeAdView.findViewById(R.id.body));
    nativeAdView.setIconView(nativeAdView.findViewById(R.id.icon));
    View headlineView = nativeAdView.getHeadlineView();
    Objects.requireNonNull(headlineView);
    ((AppCompatTextView) headlineView).setText(nativeAd.getHeadline());
    View bodyView = nativeAdView.getBodyView();
    Objects.requireNonNull(bodyView);
    ((AppCompatTextView) bodyView).setText(nativeAd.getBody());
    View callToActionView = nativeAdView.getCallToActionView();
    Objects.requireNonNull(callToActionView);
    ((AppCompatButton) callToActionView).setText(nativeAd.getCallToAction());
    MediaView mediaView = nativeAdView.getMediaView();
    Objects.requireNonNull(mediaView);
    MediaContent mediaContent = nativeAd.getMediaContent();
    Objects.requireNonNull(mediaContent);
    mediaView.setMediaContent(mediaContent);
    if (nativeAd.getIcon() == null) {
        View iconView = nativeAdView.getIconView();
        Objects.requireNonNull(iconView);
        iconView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
        View iconView2 = nativeAdView.getIconView();
        Objects.requireNonNull(iconView2);
        ((AppCompatImageView) iconView2).setImageDrawable(nativeAd.getIcon().getDrawable());
        nativeAdView.getIconView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    if (nativeAd.getStarRating() == null) {
        View starRatingView = nativeAdView.getStarRatingView();
        Objects.requireNonNull(starRatingView);
        starRatingView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
        View starRatingView2 = nativeAdView.getStarRatingView();
        Objects.requireNonNull(starRatingView2);
        ((RatingBar) starRatingView2).setRating(nativeAd.getStarRating().floatValue());
        nativeAdView.getStarRatingView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    if (nativeAd.getAdvertiser() == null) {
        View advertiserView = nativeAdView.getAdvertiserView();
        Objects.requireNonNull(advertiserView);
        advertiserView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
        View advertiserView2 = nativeAdView.getAdvertiserView();
        Objects.requireNonNull(advertiserView2);
        ((AppCompatTextView) advertiserView2).setText(nativeAd.getAdvertiser());
        nativeAdView.getAdvertiserView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    nativeAdView.setNativeAd(nativeAd);
    nativeAdView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: You should be adding the Ad Items in your main data set (generic list) on every 5th index, create separate `ViewHolders` using `getItemViewType()`, check the ViewHolder type in `onBindViewHolder` and perform appropriate action.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Embedding ads within Recyclerview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27969384/embedding-ads-within-recyclerview)